# How do I format these i,j and k's to get 2 digit values in R for loop?

Tags: r

I am running `for` loop. I have three `for` loops in one chunk.

```
for(k in 01:12){
  for (j in 01:31) {
    for (i in 00:23) {
      file = paste0("2017-", k ,"-", j ," ", i, "_00_00/Registrations.csv")
```

In this `for` loop `i`, `j` and `k`are taking values like `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,...` so on

I need to get these `i`, `j` and `k` like `00,01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12...` and so on

How do I format these `i`,`j` and `k` to get desired 2 digit values??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a loop, we can create the combination of values as a `data.frame` and then use `sprintf` to get the format

```
res <- do.call(sprintf, c(expand.grid(1:12, 1:31, 0:23),
             fmt = "2017-%02d-%02d %02d_00_00/Registration.csv"))
head(res)
#[1] "2017-01-01 00_00_00/Registration.csv" "2017-02-01 00_00_00/Registration.csv"
#[3] "2017-03-01 00_00_00/Registration.csv" "2017-04-01 00_00_00/Registration.csv"
#[5] "2017-05-01 00_00_00/Registration.csv" "2017-06-01 00_00_00/Registration.csv"
```

---

If the OP really needed the loop, just change the `paste0` with `sprintf`

```
for(k in 01:12){
 for (j in 01:31) {
   for (i in 00:23) {
    file <- sprintf("2017-%02d-%02d %02d_00_00/Registration.csv", k, j, i)  
     --
    --
  }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply.

I am not quite sure about where to put you code?

Comment: @P.Nitu  I assumed that you wanted to create a `vector` of .`.csv` strings with paths

Comment: @P.Nitu  Isn't this the same format as you showed in the post

Comment: I got it now. Thanks